# phpMyAdmin config.header.inc.php broken

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyAdmin 4.0.10 on an Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Server machine. Everything works fine, but I want to add a banner to the top of the web pages with a legal notice.

I should be able to achieve this by adding some code to the file `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.header.inc.php`, but if I add any kind of not ccommented out text to the file, phpMyAdmin doesn't load. Instead, an empty page is displayed.

Note that this happens regardless of what I write to the file: HTML code, PHP, Scripts, plain text, etc. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Check your web server log and check what's the problem.

Comment: @nKn I found two types of error in the logs: `[:error] [pid 22598] [client XXXXX] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.header.inc.php on line 9` and `[:error] [pid 25511] [client XXXXX] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.header.inc.php on line 9`. However there is no syntax error.

Comment: Well, that's why the page appears blank. You must follow the `PHP` format, not plain text, not `HTML`, just `PHP` with its syntax.

Comment: @nKn I see, I solved the problem now. Thank you for clarifying. If you write your comment as an answer I can flag my question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a blank page it very probably mean that you have a syntax error in one of your files.

The `config.header.inc.php` file must have PHP format. No plain text, HTML or any other. Once you edit it, you can check the PHP syntax with this command:

```
php -l config.header.inc.php
```